# How to Uglify Typescript files using Webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, uglifyjs

I have a webpack configuration that works perfectly with typescript until I have to minify the output bundle. I have a project that is being incrementally updated to typescript - currently one file has been migrated to typescript and it works properly when I run babel-node and my dev bundle (which doesn't use Uglify to minify the js). However, as soon as I run my prod bundle, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in main.ab0b2e37030c63351bb8.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (App) [./components/App.ts:12,0]
```

This is my webpack config:

```html
const config = {
  context: ROOT,

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/public/assets'),
    publicPath: '/assets/',
    sourcePrefix: '  ',
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "awesome-typescript-loader"
      },
      {
        enforce: "pre",
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "source-map-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          ROOT
        ],
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: DEBUG,

          babelrc: false,
          presets: [
            'react',
            'es2015',
            'stage-0',
          ],
          plugins: [
            'transform-runtime',
            [
              'react-css-modules',
              {
                context: ROOT,
                generateScopedName: CSS_SCOPE_NAME
              }
            ],
            'transform-decorators-legacy',
            ...DEBUG ? [] : [
              'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
              'transform-react-constant-elements',
              'transform-react-inline-elements'
            ],
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        loaders: [
          'isomorphic-style-loader',
          `css-loader?${JSON.stringify({
            sourceMap: DEBUG,
            modules: true,
            importLoaders: 1,
            localIdentName: CSS_SCOPE_NAME,
            minimize: !DEBUG,
          })}`,
          'postcss-loader?pack=default',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [
          'isomorphic-style-loader',
          `css-loader?${JSON.stringify({ sourceMap: DEBUG, minimize: !DEBUG })}`,
          'postcss-loader?pack=sass',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.txt$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          name: DEBUG ? '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]' : '[hash].[ext]',
          limit: 10000,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|ttf|wav|mp3)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        query: {
          name: DEBUG ? '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]' : '[hash].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  resolve: {
    root: ROOT,
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  },

  cache: DEBUG,
  debug: DEBUG,

  stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: DEBUG,
    hash: VERBOSE,
    version: VERBOSE,
    timings: true,
    chunks: VERBOSE,
    chunkModules: VERBOSE,
    cached: VERBOSE,
    cachedAssets: VERBOSE,
    errorDetails: true
  }
  
};

const clientConfig = _.merge(true, {}, config, {
  entry: './client.js',

  output: {
    filename: DEBUG ? '[name].js?[chunkhash]' : '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: DEBUG ? '[name].[id].js?[chunkhash]' : '[name].[id].[chunkhash].js',
  },

  target: 'web',

  plugins: [

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ ...GLOBALS, 'process.env.BROWSER': true }),

    new AssetsPlugin({
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
      filename: 'assets.js',
      processOutput: x => `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(x)};`,
    }),

    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(true),

    ...DEBUG ? [] : [

      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),

      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
          screw_ie8: true, // jscs:ignore requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers
          warnings: VERBOSE,
        },
      }),

      new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
    ],
  ],

  devtool: DEBUG ? 'source-map' : false,
});
```

App.ts looks like this:

```html
import * as React from 'react';
import { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const ContextType = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  insertCss: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};


class App extends React.Component<any, any> {

  static propTypes = {
    context: PropTypes.shape(ContextType).isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
  };

  static childContextTypes = ContextType;

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return this.props.context;
  }

  render() {
    return React.Children.only(this.props.children);
  }

}

export default App
```

Comment: why are you trying to uglify your TS file?  You should be uglifying the JS it generates unless I am missing something?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I want to do - uglify the JS it generates. I'm not sure why it's trying to uglify the typescript file in the first place.

Comment: Sadly I do not know WebPack so not sure if there is an error in your config file mate.  Hopefully, someone that knows WebPack will come along and help.

Answer (score 1):

That is because at the moment UglifyJsPlugin only works with es5 and you are probably using es6 or es2017. Check your tsconfig.json file and make sure it is setup to use es5